# Create words and its position in Python (Pandas) or Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I am trying to create string which will have words and its position as it appear in the input string. I tried this -

```
def wordPositions(s):
    aDict = {}
    words = s.split(' ')
    for item in words:
        position = words.index(item)
        aDict[item] = position
    return aDict


s = 'Create a string with position from a string a' 

wp = wordPositions(s) 

print(wp)
```

Its output is

```
{'Create': 0, 'a': 1 'string': 2, 'with': 3, 'position': 4, 'from': 5}
```

But I expect my output to be

```
'Create': 1, 'a': 2,7,9 'string': 3,8 'with': 4, 'position': 5, 'from': 6
```

There are three things which needs to be taken care here

1. Index t start from 1 instead of 0
2. Remove the {} of the dictionary and just have a string
3. If the word is repeating then all positions to me mentioned separated by comas

How can I achieve the desired output. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re` and `defaultdict` you might achieve what you're trying to do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

s = 'Create a string with position from a string a' 
wp = defaultdict(list)

for n, k in enumerate(s.split()):
    wp[k].append(n+1)
    
raw_output = re.search('{(.*)}', str(wp)).group(1).replace('[','').replace(']','')
final_output = re.sub("(\d), '", r"\1 '", raw_output)
```

**Output**:

```
"'Create': 1 'a': 2, 7, 9 'string': 3, 8 'with': 4 'position': 5 'from': 6"
```

Comment: Thanks Juan it worked. How can it be done in pandas or pyspark dataframe?

Comment: Each row is a string?

Comment: Hey Juan I figured that out but there is small issue in the solution We don't require the coma coming after the last value. Output should be  'Create': 1  'a': 2, 7, 9  'string': 3, 8 
 'with': 4  'position': 5  'from': 6. Each word should be separated from space only

Comment: "Patched" my response, that should work. Probably there are more direct ways, though